# Are the following range of values on $x_3$ correct given a system of inequalities with 3 variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given the system of inequalities:

\begin{align*}
x_3 &\leq \frac{x_1 + x_2 - 2}{2}\\
x_3 &\geq x_1 + 3x_2\\
x_3 &\geq 1 - x_2\\
-\frac{11}{3} &\leq x_2 \leq -3\\
13 &\leq x_1 < \infty
\end{align*}

I know that $x_1 \in [lower_{x_1}, upper_{x_1}) = [13, \infty)$ and $x_2 \in [lower_{x_2}, upper_{x_2}] = [-11/3, -3]$.

In order to find $lower_{x_3}, upper_{x_3}$, I did the following:

$lower_{x_3} = max\left\{x_1 + 3x_2, 1-x_2\right\} = \left\{upper_{x_1} + 3upper_{x_2}, 1 - upper_{x_2}\right\} = \left\{\infty, 4\right\} = \infty$

$upper_{x_3} = \frac{lower_{x_1} + lower_{x_2}-2}{2} = \frac{13 - 11/3 - 2}{2} = \frac{11}{3}$

Is the above calculation correct? In general, is $upper_{x_n} = f(lower_{x_1}, lower_{x_2}, \ldots, lower_{x_{n-1}})$ and is $lower_{x_n} = g(upper_{x_1}, upper_{x_2}, \ldots, upper_{x_{n-1}})$, where $f$ and $g$ are some real-valued functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written so far is that $x_3 \ge \infty$ and $x_3 \le \frac{11}{3}$ which doesn't make sense. In order to figure out the lower and upper bounds for $x_3$, ask yourself, "What is the largest value that $x_3$ can be?" Since $x_3 \le \frac{x_1 + x_2 -2}{2}$, we know that
$$x_3 \le \frac{\max(x_1) + \max(x_2)-2}{2} = \infty$$
So the upper bound for $x_3$ is $\infty$.

To find the lower bound, we ask, "What is the smallest value that $x_3$ can be?" Since $x_3 \ge x_1 + 3x_2$ and $x_3 \ge 1-x_2$, we can conclude the following two statements:
$$x_3 \ge \min(x_1) + 3\min(x_2) = 13 + 3\left(-\frac{11}{3}\right) = 2$$
$$x_3 \ge 1 - \max(x_2) = 1 - \left(-3\right) = 4$$

Notice we use a max in the second inequality because it will produce the smallest value.

Therefore it is true that $x_3 \ge 4$ and $x_3 \ge 2$. Since $x_3 \ge 4$ is *more restrictive*, we use that as our lower bound. So the lower bound for $x_3$ is $4$.